# undefined reference error getting while instrumenting the opentelemetry into dice server C++ application

Tags: undefined-reference, build-error

Trying to build and execute the dice server (C++) application provided by the opentelemetry, but then we are getting undefined reference build error.

```
root@kesharib:/home/maiya/otel-cpp-starter/roll-dice/build# cmake --build .
Consolidate compiler generated dependencies of target dice-server
[ 50%] Linking CXX executable dice-server
/usr/bin/ld: /home/maiya/otel-cpp-starter/opentelemetry-cpp/build/sdk/src/trace/libopentelemetry_trace.a(tracer_provider.cc.o): in function `opentelemetry::v1::sdk::common::internal_log::GlobalLogHandler::GetLogHandler()':
tracer_provider.cc:(.text._ZN13opentelemetry2v13sdk6common12internal_log16GlobalLogHandler13GetLogHandlerEv[_ZN13opentelemetry2v13sdk6common12internal_log16GlobalLogHandler13GetLogHandlerEv]+0x9): undefined reference to `opentelemetry::v1::sdk::common::internal_log::GlobalLogHandler::GetHandlerAndLevel()'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/maiya/otel-cpp-starter/opentelemetry-cpp/build/sdk/src/trace/libopentelemetry_trace.a(tracer_provider.cc.o): in function `opentelemetry::v1::sdk::common::internal_log::GlobalLogHandler::GetLogLevel()':
tracer_provider.cc:(.text._ZN13opentelemetry2v13sdk6common12internal_log16GlobalLogHandler11GetLogLevelEv[_ZN13opentelemetry2v13sdk6common12internal_log16GlobalLogHandler11GetLogLevelEv]+0x9): undefined reference to `opentelemetry::v1::sdk::common::internal_log::GlobalLogHandler::GetHandlerAndLevel()'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/maiya/otel-cpp-starter/opentelemetry-cpp/build/sdk/src/trace/libopentelemetry_trace.a(random_id_generator.cc.o): in function `opentelemetry::v1::sdk::trace::RandomIdGenerator::GenerateSpanId()':
random_id_generator.cc:(.text+0x41): undefined reference to `opentelemetry::v1::sdk::common::Random::GenerateRandomBuffer(opentelemetry::v1::nostd::span<unsigned char, 18446744073709551615ul>)'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/maiya/otel-cpp-starter/opentelemetry-cpp/build/sdk/src/trace/libopentelemetry_trace.a(random_id_generator.cc.o): in function `opentelemetry::v1::sdk::trace::RandomIdGenerator::GenerateTraceId()':
random_id_generator.cc:(.text+0xc7): undefined reference to `opentelemetry::v1::sdk::common::Random::GenerateRandomBuffer(opentelemetry::v1::nostd::span<unsigned char, 18446744073709551615ul>)'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/maiya/otel-cpp-starter/opentelemetry-cpp/build/exporters/ostream/libopentelemetry_exporter_ostream_span.a(span_exporter.cc.o): in function `opentelemetry::v1::exporter::trace::OStreamSpanExporter::OStreamSpanExporter(std::ostream&)':
span_exporter.cc:(.text+0x19a): undefined reference to `opentelemetry::v1::sdk::trace::SpanExporter::SpanExporter()'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/maiya/otel-cpp-starter/opentelemetry-cpp/build/exporters/ostream/libopentelemetry_exporter_ostream_span.a(span_exporter.cc.o): in function `opentelemetry::v1::exporter::trace::OStreamSpanExporter::~OStreamSpanExporter()':
span_exporter.cc:(.text._ZN13opentelemetry2v18exporter5trace19OStreamSpanExporterD2Ev[_ZN13opentelemetry2v18exporter5trace19OStreamSpanExporterD5Ev]+0x36): undefined reference to `opentelemetry::v1::sdk::trace::SpanExporter::~SpanExporter()'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/maiya/otel-cpp-starter/opentelemetry-cpp/build/exporters/ostream/libopentelemetry_exporter_ostream_span.a(span_exporter.cc.o):(.data.rel.ro._ZTIN13opentelemetry2v18exporter5trace19OStreamSpanExporterE[_ZTIN13opentelemetry2v18exporter5trace19OStreamSpanExporterE]+0x10): undefined reference to `typeinfo for opentelemetry::v1::sdk::trace::SpanExporter'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/maiya/otel-cpp-starter/opentelemetry-cpp/build/sdk/src/resource/libopentelemetry_resources.a(resource_detector.cc.o): in function `opentelemetry::v1::sdk::resource::OTELResourceDetector::Detect()':
resource_detector.cc:(.text+0x5f): undefined reference to `opentelemetry::v1::sdk::common::GetStringEnvironmentVariable(char const*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&)'
/usr/bin/ld: resource_detector.cc:(.text+0x7e): undefined reference to `opentelemetry::v1::sdk::common::GetStringEnvironmentVariable(char const*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
gmake[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/dice-server.dir/build.make:102: dice-server] Error 1
gmake[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:83: CMakeFiles/dice-server.dir/all] Error 2
gmake: *** [Makefile:91: all] Error 2
```

Any help would appreciated. With this we are unable to see the trace. As we are trying to see the opentelemetry trace. We have used the same dice server c++ application provided from the below link

https://opentelemetry.io/docs/languages/cpp/getting-started/

But it is not executing, instead getting build error.

Any help?